# How to pass variables to a pipeline using c#

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am triggering pipeline using the below method.Pipeline is triggering properly with out any variables. While triggering pipeline with mandatory variables I am getting exception.

```
static async Task TriggerPipeline(string organizationUrl, string personalAccessToken, string project, int pipelineId, string targetBranch)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Set the base URL for the Azure DevOps REST API
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{organizationUrl}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/");

            // Set the authorization header using the personal access token
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalAccessToken}")));

            // Set the content type header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            
            var request = new JObject();
            var resources = new JObject();
            request["resources"] = resources;
            var repositories = new JObject();
            resources["repositories"] = repositories;
            var self = new JObject();
            repositories["self"] = self;
            self["refName"] = "refs/heads/OSDeployment";
            
            var variables = new JObject();
            request["variables"] = variables;
            
            var variable1 = new JObject();
            variable1["value"] = "variable1";
            variables["variable1"] = variable1;

            var variable2= new JObject();
            variable2["value"] = "variable2";
            variables["variable2"] = variable2;

            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
            var content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                           
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1", content);

            // Check if the request was successful
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pipeline run triggered successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Response body: {responseBody}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Pipeline is triggering properly, but the variables are not passing properly. I am getting the below exception, Please help me in resolving the issue.

```
Response body: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"A value for the 'variable1' parameter must be provided.\nA value for the 'variable2' parameter must be provided.\nA ","typeName":"Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.PipelineValidationException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi","typeKey":"PipelineValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Comment: The [Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) documentation shows there is a `variables` element in the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you haven't passed the parameter value (without a default value) when running the sample pipeline like below.

```
parameters:
- name: parameter1
  # default: '' # Without default value to reproduce the issue.
steps:
- script: |
    echo "parameter1 value is ${{ parameters.parameter1 }}"
    echo "variable1 value is $(variable1)"
    echo "variable1 value is $(variable2)"
```

Based on your description, I generated the same demo and could reproduce the error when the `parameter1` was not assigned with any value.
[image]

Kindly note that when running a pipeline, the `variables` and `templateParameters` are different elements to pass. The sample code below works.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

namespace RunPipeline
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    //string organizationUrl, string personalAccessToken, string project, int pipelineId, string targetBranch
                    var organizationUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/xxAzureDevOpsOrgNamexx/";
                    var project = "xxTheProjectNamexx";
                    var personalAccessToken = "xxxxx";
                    var pipelineId = 10208;
                    // Set the base URL for the Azure DevOps REST API
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{organizationUrl}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/");

                    // Set the authorization header using the personal access token
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalAccessToken}")));

                    // Set the content type header
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var request = new JObject();
                    var resources = new JObject();
                    request["resources"] = resources;
                    var repositories = new JObject();
                    resources["repositories"] = repositories;
                    var self = new JObject();
                    repositories["self"] = self;
                    self["refName"] = "refs/heads/master";

                    var variables = new JObject();
                    request["variables"] = variables;

                    var variable1 = new JObject();
                    variable1["value"] = "variable1";
                    variables["variable1"] = variable1;

                    var variable2 = new JObject();
                    variable2["value"] = "variable2";
                    variables["variable2"] = variable2;

                    //Pass parameter into pipeline
                    var templateParameters = new JObject();
                    request["templateParameters"] = templateParameters;
                    templateParameters["parameter1"] = "parameterValue1";

                    Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
                    var content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1", content);

                    // Check if the request was successful
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Pipeline run triggered successfully.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine($"Response body: {responseBody}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The sample code passed a simple string as the value of `parameter1`. Please be also advised that parameters support other [data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#parameter-data-types).